# object on global scope causes crash when program exits

Tags: c++, memory

It looks like when t is put on global scope, then it will try to delete the pointer it stores?

error

```
kk(70137,0x1000d65c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x100b20940: pointer being freed was not allocated
kk(70137,0x1000d65c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

```
#include <set>
struct A {
    int k = 0;
};
class Test {
public:
    static std::set<A*> collection;

    ~Test(){
        collection.clear();
    }
};

Test t;
int main() {
    A* p = new A();
    t.collection.insert(p);
    delete p;
}
auto Test::collection = std::set<A*>();
```

Comment: added all the code needed

Comment: It seems you didn't understand and also didn't read the link I gave you. You are required to provide a **minimal** example. Reduce your code. Throw out everything that isn't necessary. One file that's only use is to reproduce the error.

Comment: You're mixing deallocation into your destruction, which will most likely lead to double deallocation.

Comment: @Swordfish there are less than 20 lines of code before I added the code below, and you think I need to reduce more? Btw, you highlighted “and the shorter code necessary to reproduce it”.

Comment: And watch out for the static initialisation order fiasco.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have added the complete code below. There is nothing called in any destructor I think. Could you point the deallocation out? Thanks!

Comment: *There is nothing called in any destructor I think.* – *`~Transform() { destroy(this); }`*, and you clearly didn't read the link.

Comment: @Swordfish Sorry I miss that. That line of code is used for deallocation of component that is not attached to any GameObject. I have set a point there, and this line is not called. And about the question itself, I think this is the already the minimal information to understand it.

Comment: *I think this is the already the minimal information to understand it.* – Dump all of that you posted in one file, resolve the macros by hand, throw out every function that isn't called by your minimal `main()`. Check that it still compiles and shows the error. That would be a first step towards *minimal*.

Comment: The `union` use causes undefined behaviour, it is not permitted to write one member of a union then read a different member without activating it (which invalidates any data of the previous active member)

Comment: @Swordfish alright, cleaning the macros makes the good point. Now the code should be the minimal code to reproduce the problem

Comment: @M.M Could you please be more specific? I have tested the code, and it works if the go object is inside main

Comment: @JiehongJiang my last comment is specific. Testing the code is not relevant to whether it is well-defined or not

Comment: @M.M Thanks for pointing that out, I have switched to using casting instead of union!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the [static initialisation order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) `go` may be constructed before `componentAllocator` and `collection`, they will then be destructed in the reverse order. The destructor of `GameObject` then tries to destroy a `Transform` which calls `componentAllocator` which has already been destroyed.

The simplest fix in this case is to move your `go` object inside `main()` and it will then always be destroyed before your static variables. Global variables are rarely necessary and often cause issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for your time! However, I think the problem is slightly different. I have managed to reproduce the problem using the short code above.

Comment: Your new code still shows the same issue, `Test::collection` is constructed after `t` so they are destructed in the reverse order, `Test::collection` is destructed before the destructor for `t` is run so `~Test` accesses the destroyed `collection`. Moving `t` inside `main` would again solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I think the problem is slightly different.

No, it is not. Considering your latest edit:

It is unspecified which object is destroyed first, `t` or `Test::collection`. When `Test::collection` gets destroyed first, your destructor `Test::~Test()` calls `clear()` on a set that's already dead. What business has that destructor anyway messing with static objects? Other instances of `Test` could still be around and rely on the static members data.

How about: Just don't do it?? You've been told that multiple times already.